# DIalogflow Telephony integration is interpreting SSML response from webhook as normal text

Tags: dialogflow-es

I am using dialogflow-fulfillment nodejs library to send response(eg: `agent.add("<speak>hello</speak>")`) back to the dialogflow agent. It works fine with dialogflow agent and google simulator. However, when I use the same response with telephony integration. It does not recognize it as "ssml" and speak it as "greater than speak less than....hello less than slash ..greater than>. Also. I checked SDK supported platforms and it looks like version 0.6.1 does not support telephony Platform yet.

Answer (score 4):

You are correct that the client API doesn't include methods for the telephony gateway, so you'll need to craft the JSON response yourself. This is an example of what you can put for "fulfillmentMessages":

```
fulfillmentMessages: [
    {
        platform: 'TELEPHONY',
        telephonySynthesizeSpeech: { 
            ssml: `<speak>YOUR MESSAGE GOES HERE</speak>`
        }
    }
]
```

Here's the link to the relevant API v2 beta 1 documentation (scroll down to TelephonySynthesizeSpeech): https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow-enterprise/docs/reference/rpc/google.cloud.dialogflow.v2beta1#telephonysynthesizespeech