# Playing an audio file when using Fulfillment with DialogueFlow

Tags: dialogflow-es

I'm editing the `Cloud Functions for Firebase` on the *Fulfillment* page on DialogFlow. I'm trying to respond to an `Intent` with an audio file playback. Specifically I'm targeting the **Telephony** integration.

I understand that a text message like

```
<speak><audio src="https://actions.google.com/sounds/v1/alarms/bugle_tune.ogg"></audio></speak>
```

Should play the audio.
But what is the interface to send it back so it would work?

Just using `agent.add()` doesn't seem to work (it reads the SSML string outloud)

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use the client API library to do this at this time. You'll need to craft the JSON response yourself. Please see my answer here which should be helpful: [DIalogflow Telephony integration is interpreting SSML response from webhook as normal text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53147924/dialogflow-telephony-integration-is-interpreting-ssml-response-from-webhook-as-n/53324733#53324733)

Basically do the same but use TelephonyPlayAudio instead of TelephonySynthesizeSpeech.